# Implement this within a canvas and have text over it

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I want to implement [this](https://codepen.io/abergin/pen/bdOZKo) and have some text over it. The problem I'm facing is implementing this on the canvas and having a div over it. Please help!

I tried with positioning the canvas -

```
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#container canvas, #overlay {
  position: absolute;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: How does this relate to JavaScript?

Comment: If #overlay doesn't need eventing then tell #overlaying to not listen to events with #overlay{pointer-events:none;}.  If #overlay must respond to events then make #overlay the same size as the canvas. Then listen for mouse events on #overlay and use those same mouse coordinates to drive your canvas animations.

Comment: CoffeeScript would be a more appropriate tag it seems.